# Prints words based on their probabilities

Tags: python, probability

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

Write a program that prints "I love" followed by one word: the additional word should be 'dogs' with 80% probability, 'cats' with 10% probability, and 'bats' with 10% probability.Here's an example output:

```
I love bats
```

**EXAMPLE**

The following program prints out the word 'dog' with 20% probability  (Python code)

```
import random
prob = 0.20

if random.random() < prob:
    print('dog')
```

Why does it print 'dog' with 20% probability? The idea is to draw a random value between 0.00 and 1.01 – that's what the function random() in module random does – and to check whether it is less than the required probability value expressed as a decimal number. For example, the probability that the random value falls between 0.00 and 0.50 is 50%. The probability that the value falls between 0.50 and 1.0 is also 50%. The probability that it falls between 0.00 and 0.20 is 20%, and so forth.
Original exercise on [Elements of AI: Building AI, chapter 1](https://buildingai.elementsofai.com/Getting-started-with-AI/hill-climbing)

**WHAT I CAN'T UNDERSTAND:**

I need to print one only word: bats, cats or dogs. How can I print one when both cats and bats have exactly same 10% probability. An **if** condition can not differentiate between 0.10 and 0.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of a stick of length 1. You break the stick into 3 pieces (so that the whole stick is used). The first part is .8 of the length of the stick, the second part is .1 and the last part is .1... Now you draw a random variable with `random.random()` and see which part of the stick it lands on. So the two .1 probabilities land on different parts of the stick:

```
r = random.random()
if r < .8:
     print('dogs')
elif r < .9:
     # here we have .1 = .9 - .8
     print('cats')
else:
    # this is the final part of the stick so we know we are in this bit if not in the others
    print('bats')
```

---

Edit (thanks to @traal no need for numpy here):
Just to be complete about this answer you can also use random to sample from the array at the correct probabilities:

```
choice = random.choices(["dogs", "cats", "bats"], [.8, .1, .1])
```

Comment: No need to use NumPy for that; it's in the standard library!
random.choices(("dogs", "cats", "bats"), (80, 10, 10))
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Answer (score 0):

in the simplestway you can have a `list` that contains the desired word and print it by a `randon` key number

```
from random import randrange
words = ["dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","cats","bats"]
print(words[randrange(10)])
```

Comment: When one develops software, precision is important. You don't have an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: @Matthias yes your rigt. Thanks for advice